# Using clipboardjs in typescript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, typescript, typescript-typings, clipboard.js

I am developing an application using ASP.NET Webforms and I am having difficulty in using clipboardjs with TypeScript.

**What I have tried:**

a. Downloaded clipboardjs (https://clipboardjs.com/) and added its reference under script folder.

b. Installed clipboardjs typings using nuget.

c. Installed jquery and its typings and added jquery reference to project.

See the file details below,

[image]

Now, when I tried to follow their documentation and put some code, I am getting "Cannot find the name Clipboard" error in typescript.

[image]

What am I missing? Any suggestion / help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript 2.0+? or are you using a module loader/bundler like Require.js, System.js, Webpack, or Browserify? Depending on that, the solution here can be made easier.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser In my visual studio project, I noticed that the typescript tool version is: 1.8. I am not using a module loader. Can you guide me on that?

Comment: If you'd be able to upgrade to TypeScript 2.1, I can make an update to the declaration file on DefinitelyTyped so that you can use it.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser, sure. I can upgrade to TypeScript 2.1. Please let me know once you have updated the declaration file.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser, Also, if you could explain why I should upgrade to TypeScript 2.1, it will be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that the declaration file needs to be re-authored to work for both globals and modules, but the typings tool isn't compatible with the new format necessary to use that. You'll be able to use `@types` - the recommended way to get the declaration files as explained [here in this blog post.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Comment: Hi @vimalan-jaya-ganesh, if my answer below is acceptable, please consider marking it so by clicking on the check-mark.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on TypeScript 2.0 or later, you can get declaration files for clipboard by running

```
npm install @types/clipboard
```

At that point, if you're not able to just write `new Clipboard` in your file without getting an error, you need to add `"clipboard"` to the `"types"` field in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["clipboard"]
    }
}
```

This will tell TypeScript to walk up the directory chain and try to find types for the `clipboard` package in each `node_modules` folder.